# WPF application with EF6 does not create new database in SQL Server Enterprise

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I am working on a WPF application and using entity framework 6 code first for database but when I run the application, the database is not created in the SQL Server Enterprise. I googled a lot but could not find any suitable solution for this, I thank everyone in advance.

Below is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
       <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, 
       Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>    
   </configSections>

   <connectionStrings>
         <add name="DbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial 
         Catalog=CricketAcademy;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>


   <startup> 
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
   </startup>
   <entityFramework>
       <providers>
           <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
           type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
       </providers>
   </entityFramework>
  </configuration>
```

This is my Context Class:

```
class Db : DbContext
{
    public Db() : base("name=DbConnectionString")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player_Phone> PlayerPhones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Admission> Admissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fee> Fees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coach> Coaches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }

}
```

And here is my MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Db DB = new Db();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add migrations if they don't exist. And then use dbmigrator in code.

Comment: @Anton : Can't we do it without migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the constructor of your `DbContext`:

```cs
public Db() : base("name=DbConnectionString")
{
      Database.SetInitializer<Db>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Db>());
}
```

You can find more information [in this article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added the line to my constructor but it still does not create the database in SQL Server.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani How do you check that database has been created? Are you trying to access it using dbcontext or do you watch it in SQL server explorer (other programs). EF6 has to call this initializer on first access to the database. Creating dbcontext is not accessing db.

Comment: I go to SQL Server and check if the database is created but I can't find it there.

Comment: As I said, try to call `var players = DB.Players` or other code to access db using your dbContext. On this action it will create database automatically.  If you want to create db with code manually, you should use migrations and migrator